# Defining widgets inside initState or class constructors rather than build?

Tags: flutter

Most of the examples and prevailing wisdom I see use a typical template for a Widget within a class, where ALL further widgets are created within the `build` method (which I think can give a clarity of code, but setting this aside).

However, if the referenced widget is not going to change further, it still gets recreated every build call. Is there any actual issue with assigning this in an `initState` or the class constructor and referencing it later ?

Trivialised example

```
// this partial from inside the build() method currently
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: Text(
      'Oeschinen Lake Campground',
       style: TextStyle(
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

to

```
// Now inside initState or class Constructor
myText = Text(
      'Oeschinen Lake Campground',
       style: TextStyle(
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
 );

...
// Still inside build method (in fact this could also go inside the constructor ?)
Container( 
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
  child: myText
)
```

This is just for code that isn't based on a state reference.

Are there any downsides other than design/aesthetics to doing it this way ? Whilst this example is trivial, I keep thinking that maybe there are some performance/battery/headspace benefits to not keep having to rebuild non state based widgets when the app gets a lot more complex (I'm also aware I think that a Widget further up the tree may still call for a new object each time). However, I'm new to flutter/dart, so wary about some issues I haven't considered properly, or fundamentally misunderstood some aspects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a legitimate optimization. In fact you can even do the same with state dependent widgets (combined with `didUpdateWidget`).
The win is negligible though.

Widgets are extremely light, and Dart is optimized for a lot of micro instantiations.

And there's one problem wih this approach: you loose hot-reload.

---

Reusing old widget instances is still pretty useful. As if the widget instance don't change, Flutter abort the subtree build.

This is used very often in animations to *not* rebuild the entire widget tree every frames. A typical example would be `AnimatedBuilder` (but all `XXTransition` follow the same logic)

```
Animation animation;

AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: animation,
  child: Text('Foo'),
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment(.5, animation.value),
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

Here, this voluntarily reuse the `child` instance so that `Text` build method doesn't get called again.

---

**So, should I do it or not?**

Well, yes and no. It is always cool to optimize your application. But instead of doing it using variables there's a better way : const constructors.

To reuse your example, you could extract your "always the same" widget tree into a custom widget with a const constructor:

```
class _Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Foo({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Oeschinen Lake Campground',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then use it this way inside your `build` method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: const _Foo(),
  );
}
```

This way you get the benefits of caching the widget instance. BUT you don't loose hot reload.

Perfect right?

Comment: I hadn't realised about the hot-reload aspect, and that had been confusing me also, so this ties a few things together, many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR**: Don't.

---

First, let's see what Googler and Flutter engineer Matt Sullivan [has to say about this topic](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30):

> With Flutter creating and destroying objects with great frequency,
>   should developers take steps to limit this behavior? It’s not uncommon
>   to see new Flutter developers create references to widgets they know
>   will not change over time, and place them in state so that they won’t
>   be destroyed and rebuilt.
>
> Don’t do this.

In order to understand why this is a bad idea, you first of all need to understand that `Widget`s do **very little**.
Because they usually just compose other `Widget`s or instantiate `RenderObject`s, they don't do the actual rendering; all the heavy lifting is done by `RenderObject`s.
You can think of the `Widget`s as super-lightweight "blueprints" for `RenderObject`s.
Also note that `RenderObject`s get heavily cached by the Flutter framework itself, so if you create some similar `Widget` in consecutive builds, the underlying `RenderObject` [is automatically reused](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUfXWzp0-DU).
**By caching your UI, you are effectively re-creating a functionality which Flutter's rendering pipeline provides out of the box**.
Solely because of that, many people would argue the added complexity to your code isn't worth it.

*"Okay then,"* you might think,
*"The performance benefit may be very very small, but it does exist, right?"*

Actually, no.
That's because the underlying Dart runtime uses two types of garbage collectors: the *Young Space Scavenger* garbage collector for short-lived objects and the *mark-sweep* garbage collector for long-lived objects.
For a more detailed explanation about how they work, check out [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30) fittingly named "Don't Fear the Garbage Collector".
Basically, it says that the *Young Space Scavenger* is much faster than the *mark-sweep* collector and if an app doesn't adhere to the "weak generational hypothesis" which states that most objects die young, then the *mark-sweep*ing will occur more often.
Put short, **performance might actually get worse**.

**To sum it up, re-implementing a built-in Flutter feature while making your code less readable and your app slower is probably not the right way to go.**