# Filled with messages "Background concurrent copying GC freed 320389(9MB)" in flutter terminal

Tags: memory, flutter, dart

I'm retrieving data from firetstore with the help of StreamBuilder() widget but showing contineously circular progessing bar and my terminal is filled with `Background concurrent copying GC freed 320389(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 9MB/19MB, paused 96us total 118.879ms` messages.

I have searched for it and I know it's not an error or any exception according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117311/flutter-log-getting-background-concurrent-copying-gc-freed-message). but throws me problem during fetch data.

I'm running it on real device, my logic isn't containing huge amount of data,

code:

```
child:StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: firestore.collection('Gift').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                  if (snapshot.hasError){
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                  } 
                  if (!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white,),);
                  } else{
                   // my logic
                  final int eventCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
                     String todaysDate= DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now()) ;
                       List<String> getGiftDates=[];
                       List<String> getNumber=[];
                       List<String> getGainStatus= [];
                       List<String> getDescription= [];
                       for(int i=0; i<eventCount;i++){
                         if(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toString()== todaysDate){
                          getGiftDates.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toString());
                          getNumber.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['userMobileNumber']);
                          getGainStatus.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['GainStatus']);
                          getDescription.add(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Description']);

                        }else{
                          print("No dates matched");
                        }
                       }
                      //after that showing data in the form of text.
                      return Column(
                         ......
                       )

                      } 
                   }
                )
```

Comment: it happens to me, I wonder if anyone has idea here?

Comment: Are you using for loop ? if you're then replace with forEach , because for loop makes our code heavy loading , so it takes time. I'm not sure it resolve your issue but I suggest, for healthy coding don't use for loop in build method and what's your device RAM?