# I want to check if any Widget exist in a List?

Tags: flutter

I want to load pages from a List and when the user taps on an item from the drawer he can go to that page (if it's already opened) otherwise the Widget will load in the selected page. 
But I can't find if that widget is already exists in the List `if(myList.contains(Widget1())) => print('it exist');` One guy told me to override `hashCode` and `operator==`

```
class Widget6 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = 'Widget6';

  final Icon icon = Icon(Icons.assessment); 



      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: icon,
    );
  }

 @override
      bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
        final Widget6 typedOther = other;
        return title == typedOther.title && icon == typedOther.icon;
      }

      @override
          int get hashCode => hashValues(title, icon);
}
```

if I do that I can't use any child widget to those widgets. Getting exception like: `type 'Center' is not a subtype of type 'Widget6'`. I copied this from flutter gallery I didn't find good documentation/guide. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Complete code below

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List pageList = [
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
    Widget3(),
    Widget4(),
  ];

  PageController _pageController;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: _selectedIndex,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  void navigatePage(Widget widget) {
// problem is here
    if (pageList.contains(widget)) {
      _pageController.animateToPage(pageList.indexOf(widget, 0),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
    }

    else {
      setState(() {
        pageList.removeAt(_pageController.page.toInt());
        pageList.insert(_pageController.page.toInt(), widget);
      });
      _pageController.animateToPage(_pageController.page.toInt(),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget1'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget1(),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget2'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget2(),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget3'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget3(),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget4'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget4(),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget5'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget5(),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Widget6'),
              onTap: () => navigatePage(
                Widget6(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        onPageChanged: (newPage) {
          setState(() {
            this._selectedIndex = newPage;
          });
        },
        controller: _pageController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            child: pageList[index],
          );
        },
        itemCount: pageList.length,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
          _pageController.animateToPage(index,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
        }),
        items: pageList.map((page) {
          return BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              icon: page.icon,
              title: Text(page.title));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here List of dummy Widgets

```
class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = 'Widget1';

  final Icon icon = Icon(Icons.school);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: icon,
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  // only title and icon are changed
}

class Widget3 extends StatelessWidget {
  // only title and icon are changed
}

class Widget4 extends StatelessWidget {
  // only title and icon are changed
}

class Widget5 extends StatelessWidget {
 // only title and icon are changed
}
class Widget6 extends StatelessWidget {
 // only title and icon are changed
}
```

Comment: One solution would be to use a key in your widgets, then use methods like removeWhere and so on to find/remove... a specific widget.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand. Why you want use if(page List.contains(widget)? Widget is not create in List pageList=[Widget1(),...]?

Comment: @NorbertoMartínAfonso To check whether the Page is already opened or not, based on that I either navigate to that Page or open the selected on.

Comment: Have you think to use SharedPreferences and save page visited for example: widgetonevisited=true and check SharedPreferences at initstate?

Comment: @NorbertoMartínAfonso Everything is working now if  I use `operator ==` inside those dummy Widgets. But I am getting an exception that `type 'Center' is not a subtype of type 'Widget1'`. more specifically I can't use any child widget.

Comment: @NoobN3rd No I can't make it work using key. I have to check if that widget is exist or not? 
eg
`List myList = [Widget1(), Widget2(), Widget3(),];
if(myList.contains(Widget1())) => print('it exist');`

Comment: I found the solution. 
I missed this sentence 
`if (runtimeType != other.runtimeType) return false;` 
while overriding operator ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. And it has to do with `operator==` overriding
I missed this line  `if (runtimeType != other.runtimeType) return false;` 
The whole code stays the same.

```
@override
  // ignore: hash_and_equals
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (runtimeType != other.runtimeType) return false;
    final Widget6 typedOther = other;
    return title == typedOther.title;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ahmed Sorry for the late reply, I decided to put it in an answer rather than a comment.

One solution is yours, overriding `==` but I was thinking of using `Key` and then instead of using `contains` method, using something like:

```dart
if(myList.indexWhere((Widget widget)=> widget.key==_key) != -1)...
```

### Suggestion

You can store icon and title as a map or a module instead of making 6 different Widget.

You can create another file, saying `module.dart` like this:

```dart
class Module {
  final String title;
  final Icon icon;

  Module(this.title, this.icon);

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(title.hashCode, icon.hashCode);

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    if (!identical(this, other)) {
      return false;
    }
    return other is Module &&
        this.title.compareTo(other.title) == 0 &&
        this.icon == other.icon;
  }
}
```

Then create another file that builds the page, saying `mywidget.dart`, like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Module module;
  MyWidget({Key key,@required this.module}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: module.icon,
    );
  }
}
```

Then on each ListTile's `onTap`, Navigate like this:

```dart
...
ListTile(
    title: Text('Widget1'),
    onTap: () => navigatePage(
     MyWidget(module: Module('Widget1', Icon(Icons.school)),)
    ),
  ),
...
```

So instead of storing Widgets, you store a Type(Here Module) that you declared.

You can also use the list's `map` to build each `ListTile` of the `ListView` for each Module, instead of doing it one by one. (if each item on the drawer are similar), Something like this:

```dart
 List<Module> myTabs = [
      Module('Widget1', Icon(Icons.school)),
      Module('Widget2', Icon(Icons.home)),
    ];
...
    Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children:myTabs.map((Module module)=> ListTile(
          title:Text( module.title),
          onTap: navigatePage(MyWidget(module: module,)),
        )).toList(),
      ) ,
    );
...
```

Comment: It's not late at all, I appreciate your answer. I will definitely try this and let you know. Can you tell me is there any good reason not to Store `Widget` in a List maybe Performance issue?

Comment: @Ahmed Hope it helps you, For your question I refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856438/defining-widgets-inside-initstate-or-class-constructors-rather-than-build/52857341#52857341) and my reasons why I prefer it is that I guess comparing module instances rather than widgets is a better option and also if you want to change the widget even a little bit(like adding title beside the icon), you only need to do it once not 6 times and so on.